# What is a tidy algorithm to find overlapping intervals?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but I'm not finding it: I'm only finding related, but harder questions.

I've got four points, representing two lines like this:

```
       A         C      B   D
|------*---|-----+----|-*---+---|----------|
0          10         20        30         40
```

So in the example, `AB = {7, 21}` and `CD = {16,26}`. (The lines could be in any relation to each other, and any size.) I want to find out whether or not they overlap, and by how much if so. (In the example, the answer would be 5.) My current solution involves a bunch of complicated if/then steps, and I can't help but think there's a nice arithmetical solution. Is there?

(P.S. Really, I'm doing bounding-box intersection, but if I can get it in one dimension, the other will be the same, obviously.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
intersects = (max(a,b) > min(c,d)) && (min(a,b) < max(c,d))
overlap = min(max(a,b), max(c,d)) - max(min(c,d), min(a,b))
```

If you can assume `a <= b` and `c <= d`:

```
intersects = (b > c) && (a < d)
overlap = min(b, d) - max(c, a)
```

You can also calculate `intersects` as follows:

```
intersects = (overlap > 0)
```

Comment: I want the amount of overlap, not just whether or not they do. Thanks, though.

Comment: @sprugman: it would be pretty easy to extrapolate Mark's code to compute the amount of intersection.

Comment: Which he did for me, Matt. Thanks, Mark! :)

Comment: won't `max(a,b)` always be `b`, and at least as I've set up the problem? and `min(c,d)` is always `c`? etc.?

Comment: @sprugman: If you assume that `a <= b` and `c <= d` then yes. I didn't see anywhere in your question where you stated that it was safe to make this assumption, so I didn't make it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Mark, good point. In which case we get `overlap = min(b, d) - max(c, a)` which is the kind if tidiness I was talking about! :^,

Answer (score 0):

A line segment is the intersection of two opposing rays (two half-infinite lines in opposite directions). You have two line segments to intersect -- the result is the intersection of all 4 rays. So you can factor your code as three successive ray-intersections: the leftward of the left-facing rays intersected with the rightward of the right-facing rays.

(This is another way of stating the now-accepted answer.)